# Mobile network sign disappears, replaced by "stop sign" icon

Tags: samsung, mobile-network, notification-icons

I am using Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 N8000 device. I have SIM card inserted for mobile data usage. First time, it is working as I captured status bar image as shown with mobile data sign :-

[image]

but after some time, mobile data sign disappears and "stop" sign appeared as shown in the picture :-

[image]

What does that stop sign mean?

Comment: This my appear when your mobile provider network is down. No signal at all, so sim appears as out of service.

Comment: The bar sign is the Priority Interruption icon. But setting the Priority interruption to "None" won't turn off the Network signal. You can change the Priority Interruption settings simply by pressing the volume up key. What is displayed when you call a number?

Comment: @Lucky apparently, [it's the same](https://www.google.com/search?q=samsung+galaxy+no+signal+icon&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIpterruvQyAIVDr-OCh3TzQLU&biw=1575&bih=965) :/

Comment: @user3344236 consider post that as an answer, since I think it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon will appear when your mobile provider network is down. No signal at all, so SIM appears as out of service.

[image: IMG:]

<sup>(Image courtesy of [Android Central's Forum](http://forums.androidcentral.com/sprint-galaxy-s-ii-epic-4g-touch/235715-unknown-icon-notification-bar-unable-turn-searching-service-off.html#post2441445))</sup>